# Can an acknowledgement section of a thesis contain names of music bands?

Tags: thesis, acknowledgement

Can I add some music bands in the acknowledgement section of my bachelor thesis? I used to listen these bands during all my 3-year long studies and during all the writing of my thesis, so I think they helped me quite a lot.

Comment: Of course, if you are an electronic engineer writing a thesis on power converters you should absolutely acknowledge the AC/DCs. And if you are a physicists working on particle accelerators, you should acknowledge the Van der Graaf Generator band ;-)

Comment: I did it in mine. You are quite free to put whatever you want in the acknowledgement section. The game in the lab where I did my PhD was to read the section to find the hidden jokes. Just remember that what you write there will stay there forever...

Comment: I've flagged this as a possible duplicate because even though the question is different the answer is essentially: "Thank whoever you want to thank."

Comment: The duplicate flag is for actual duplicate questions, not questions that admit the same answer. Canonical counterexample is 2+2 and 2×2.

Comment: @R.. We don't want to have a separate question for any possible thankable subject. That could serve as a canonical answer.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - I agree with the concept you have expressed.  However, the girlfriend etc. question isn't worded in a general enough way.  How about you write a general question, in canonical form?  I haven't figured out the "community" thing yet -- perhaps that would be appropriate, though?

Comment: @aparente001 Usually the need of canonical Q&A is firstly discussed on meta (see [tag:canonical-question]). In this case, I don't know how the question could be formulated in a general way with an answer that says anything different from those already existing, or which simply becomes a list of thankable subjects.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano - see if these options give you some ideas: "What am I allowed to put in my thesis acknowledgements section?"  "Can an acknowledgement section of a thesis contain _______?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only two unwritten rules of thesis acknowledgment sections are as follows:

1. Thank your advisor. (Preferably first. Yes, even before God if you're religious.)
2. Don't say anything outright offensive.

Other than that, go nuts!

Comment: Yes I forgot to say that I first thanked my advisor, my co-advisor and my family.. :D

Comment: I'm definitely going to be acknowledging Subway Restaurants in my thesis then.

Comment: Agreed -- a thesis is a rare "individual" piece of work, and you can certainly use the acknowledgements to offer whatever personal thanks and comments you like. (Note: I'm a professor, and have read many dissertations.)

Comment: I thanked Gygax, cola manufacturers, and "the states of Alaska and confusion". Have fun...