# Acknowledgements in a bachelor thesis: Is it etiquette conform to thank for non thesis related things?

Tags: etiquette, acknowledgement, bachelor

As I'm about to finish my bachelor thesis, I'm at writing the acknowledgement section.

How far can I go here in terms of non-thesis-related stuff? 
Is there room for humorous acknowledgements (like thanking my coworker for his great taste in music or bad puns), or is that rather something to be left out?

Comment: The usual rule is to say what you want in the acknowledgement (with some reasonable boundary conditions), but it would help to look at other bachelors' acknowledgement sections as well. I haven't actually seen bachelor theses with acknowledgement sections, but i'm not sure what is standard in your country :)

Comment: Lots of PhD theses (including some of the best) are doing that, so, yes. (Bachelor theses are supposed to imitate PhD theses in style at least.)

Comment: This ground has been covered, e.g. http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/77180/can-an-acknowledgement-section-of-a-thesis-contain-names-of-music-bands, http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38509/whether-and-how-to-thank-a-girlfriend-or-boyfriend-in-the-acknowledgements-of-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acknowledgment part is your own part, write what ever you want in humour, fun etc but don't cross the boundaries that might hurt some people feeling. here is a sample from MIT, you can give a read.
http://www.mit.edu/~alvarso/thesis-phd/Acknowledgements.pdf